# beamer/align: How to exchange a single symbol in an animation

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to replace an equals-sign in an align environment by a \ne in a LaTeX beamer animation. The following is a MnWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{.}
\begin{align*}
    a \onslide<1>{=}\onslide<2>{\ne} b
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here, the (not-)equals sign changes place, which is obviously undesirable.

I have done this before by using an overprint environment around the \onslides, but that has to be outside of the align environment, otherwise it breaks. I'm not willing to go for that solution this time, because what is a and b from the example are actually huge terms, and there are several following. I would have to duplicate all that.

Is there a tiny solution to that without so much duplication?

Note: There are multiple occurences of the sign to be replaced.

Comment: Use `a &\only<1>{=}\only<2>{\ne} b`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX (although the question is 'answered' already)

Comment: @Caesar, note the use of the alignment char `&` if you will add other lines. If not, don't use `align`. Use `equation*`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments